# I can't run artisan commands on ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-artisan

I've recently moved from windows to Ubuntu, I installed php7, mysql, composer and also laravel via `composer global require "laravel/installer"`. But when I try to run a command like : `php artisan serve` it gave me this error:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(/home/slim/Desktop/ss/hh/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/slim/Desktop/ss/hh/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17 PHP Fatal
>   error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/slim/Desktop/ss/hh/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /home/slim/Desktop/ss/hh/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

Do you run composer update? If you clone it from a repository it wont include vendor directory so it will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your `composer`:

```
composer update
```

OR

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

After you can clear the cache :

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: it gives me the same error when I try to run any command of those

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error only shows on laravel's new versions 5+, when I create a 4+ laravel project it is not showing this error

Answer (score 0):

This issue may cause by the conflict when the composer tries to install the obsolete package/plugin in.

Try to remove the unused package/plugin in "composer.json". For example, mine has trouble installing "werneckbh/qr-code". Then, edit the "composer.json", remove the entry for "werneckbh/qr-code".

Save, then run composer install/ composer update.

Hope it helps.

[The error in composer install.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hKoC.png)